# What is causing a white scale buildup at copper pin connection on LED light sticks and how can they be cleaned?

Tags: led, current, connector, troubleshooting, low-voltage

Can someone explain what is causing this white scale to appear on the copper pins and on the block of this LED light connection? The seal at the connection is supposed to be watertight. On occasion, there is a white (crystallization) that forms at the PC board, pin and on the block at this connection. These lights are exposed to sun and rain and are located 5 miles from coastal waters. There is power and data flowing through these connects and both get affected causing the lights to go out.[image]!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tFew.jpg)[image][image][image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: The powdery scale looks like it's the same both on the outside and on the inside of the connector.  Do you have an IP (Ingress Protection) rating for the seal?

Comment: Seems like typical water infiltration. You should probably use dielectric grease to prevent this if you can't change the seal.

Comment: The IP rating is 65, and we are not allowed to add anything to the connection per the manufacturer.

Comment: Right now you clearly have water getting inside, so that's definitely "something".  "Adding anything to the connection" probably means electronically. Dielectric grease isn't anything that will ruin a warranty. Only thing that can solve this is a change of seal, or adding something to prevent water infiltration. If you leave it like that chances are it's going to stop working completely once rust corrodes the interior.

Comment: So is the white substance mineral deposits from rain water? If so, why would it not collect on all of the pins?

Comment: @Needtoknow I favor the water infiltration theory, but you could also check the metals used in both the pins and the socket.  Once you find that, Google for "Galvanic Series" and locate a table to see if you should expect corrosion with that combination.  Perhaps your problem is even a combination of these two.

Comment: How confident are you that your install was completely dry?  Do you have multiple devices affected?  If so, is the corrosion or buildup present on the same pins on each of them?

Comment: We have over 30 floors of this material on a building and most of it went from the shipping crate to being installed. There has been a very small percentage of connections being affected by corrosion. This white material builds up on top of the copper surface and builds up similar to barnacles on submerged pilings of a pier. And how would this white material stick to the surface of a plastic block?

Comment: @Needtoknow If you are saying that this is affecting a small percent of installed equipment on 30 floors of a building, then I think you have both a moisture (could be condensation onto something else that eventually dissolves, as it moves, some small amount of compounds) and also a problem with differential voltages which is forcing this dissolute to precipitate at the connector's connection points. The fact that only some pins in a connector, and not others, experience the problem far more is also suggestive of this kind of problem.

Comment: Can you open one and see if the deposits are present inside too? Do you know if there are batteries in the lights?

Comment: To clarify... signs of moisture are the small percentage of outages... differential voltages seem to be closer to the problem... the outer pair of pins flow power, the inner 2 pair flow data. I have not cut open a block yet, I might be able to next week. Another note; I sliced a piece of white buildup off of the side of a pin and found the underside was a solid color blue.

Answer (score 5):

Copper is a material that corrodes, just like any other. When [copper corrodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verdigris), it will turn into copper carbonate (Cu2CO3(OH)2), but near the sea it might become copper chloride (Cu2(OH)3Cl) as well. When water is involved, like in your case, there may be an effect called [efflorescence.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Efflorescence) Efflorescence "is the migration of a salt to the surface of a porous material, where it forms a coating". This usually forms in a crystal form, since it's formed of salt. This is what creates the white buildup sometimes found on water pipes for example:

[image: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/86004/green-and-white-stuff-on-copper-pipes]
https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/86004/green-and-white-stuff-on-copper-pipes

In your case it's the same:
[image]

So basically, you're getting water infiltration. The easiest solution to solve this is using dielectric grease. Or get a better seal for your electronics.

Comment: I appreciate and thank all of you for responses. I will move forward with these ideas to find answers. As I uncover more info, I will update what I find.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with the theory of water ingress.
On top of that I would like to add following.

IP65 has a complete protection against water jets and is dust proof.
The protection level itself forms a part of the problem due to the following.

1. A lower temperature of the enclosure in relation to the surrounding air causes a difference in pressure with an inflow of outside air as result. If the temperature becomes low enough the moisture in the air starts to condense. Compare this with dew in the morning. Now the trouble starts.
2. Water can't escape. Only when the inside enclosure temperature becomes high enough to evaporate the water or prevent condensation in the first place **and** the inside presure becomes higher than the outside pressure the vapour is forced out and corrosion is prevented.
3. Any encloser with enough heat production or forced dry air is able to fulfill these conditions. The connector presented by OP does not fulfill these conditions and corrosion can not be prevented.
4. The only way out is to use enclosures that can ventilate to the outside and yet are protected against splash or sprayed water.  For this the IP standard does not yet offer any help.

You can try to clean but the problem remains.

Comment: @SamGibson. It is the principle that is causing the problem for any enclosure. We have and had similar problems with light fixtures in a harbor. Replaced all with complety sealed units and sealed also the in comming connection with resin

Comment: Thanks very much for updating it - the answer makes perfect sense after changing "armature" to "enclosure".

Comment: I have had an opportunity to open up the female connection block and found a hole full of a white, silicone type substance. This appears to build up in the prong connection and completely insulates the prong. I would not expect water to have this affect. Could this be an organic type growth? Again, this material is soft and rubbery to the touch and has a shiny surface.